# Sencha touch customise rest proxy url

Tags: url, rest, parameters, sencha-touch-2

I need to pass addition param to jersey server. But how do I submit my url like **..get/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}**

Here is my js file

```
  Ext.define('bluebutton.view.BlueButton.testing', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    xtype: 'testing',
       requires: [

    'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.TransactionList',
    'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberPopUp',
     'bluebutton.view.BlueButton.MemberDetail',
     'bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList',

    ],
    config: {
     id:'register',
        items :[

              {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'name',
                    label: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                    name: 'email',
                    label: 'Email'
                },

                 {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Send',
                    handler: function(button) {
                        var form = Ext.getCmp('register');
                          values = form.getValues();






//        Select record
        //If load data , restful will using "get",  url will be /users/1
        var User = Ext.ModelMgr.getModel('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList');
        User.load(123,
         {
            success: function(user) {
            alert(user.get('fullName'));




            }
        }
        );



                    }
                }


        ],


   }

});
```

Model.js

```
Ext.define('bluebutton.model.BlueButton.MemberList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        idProperty: 'memberModel',
        fields: [
            { name: 'fullName' },
            { name: 'singer' },

        ],

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
           url: 'http://localhost:8080/RESTFulExample/rest/json/metallica/get',
            reader: 'json',
            actionMethods: {
                create: 'GET',
                read: 'POST',
                update: 'PUT',
                destroy: 'DELETE'
            },



            reader: {
                type: 'json',

            },

            writer: {
                type: 'json',

            },
        }

    }

});
```

But now I only able to pass my url like **..get/123** Please guide me some solution.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

2 things coming to my mind, First do not write proxy inside model definition, instead set it in initialize function of store where you can look at config data and create url on its basis. e.g.

```
initialize: function() {
        var myId = this.config.uid;
        this.setProxy({
        type: 'rest',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/RESTFulExample/rest/json/metallica/get/'+myId,
        reader: 'json',
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'GET',
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'PUT',
            destroy: 'DELETE'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',

        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',

        },
    });
}
```

and you can pass id to load when you create the store like this:

```
    var memberStore = Ext.create('bluebutton.store.BlueButton.MemberList', {
        uid : 123
    });
```

2nd way could be writing your own proxy extending `Ext.data.proxy.Rest` and implementing `buildUrl` such that it checks for data and append it to url. e.g.

```
buildUrl: function(request) {
    var me      = this,
        url     = me.callParent(arguments);
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(someData)){
        url = Ext.urlAppend(url, "data="+someData);
    }
    return url;
}
```

I hope it helps.

**EDIT**
Sample code for custom proxy which I have used in past to append some token to every request

```
Ext.define('myapp.proxy.CustomJsonpProxy', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',
  alias: 'proxy.customjsonpproxy',
  buildUrl: function(request) {
    var me      = this,
    url     = me.callParent(arguments);
    if(!Ext.isEmpty(loggedInUserToken)){
      url = Ext.urlAppend(url, "token="+loggedInUserToken);
    }
    return url;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur reply. I am new for sencha touch. For the 2nd way. How can i override Ext.data.proxy.Rest? can give me more example ?

Comment: In addition. for the 1st way, I tink I should add something like "store.sync" then only will summit url to jersey server ,rite? sorry for my noob qestion

Comment: Check my edited answer for sample code of custom proxy.

Regarding first approach, instead of sync you have load function which you can call whenever you want provided you have set `autoLoad:false` in store.

Comment: ok. bro . thanks .U really help me alot. i try first. Btw can i have u email , in case i got any question can ask u again

Comment: You are most welcome. If you want to ask more questions post here only, I don't prefer email communication because this is much better platform to discuss ideas.
BTW if this works please mark my answer & upvote.

Comment: I know I'm not OP, but that custom proxy saved my life! I need to get the user's ID from local storage and append it to the URL. Would you happen to know how to escape the `&` that is automatically appended before our value?

Answer (score 0):

the below code worked for me....to set a param to an url

```
myStore.getProxy().getApi().read = myStore.getProxy().getApi().read + param;
```